# JSF/ Facelets different views for different users

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have to implement a mechanism that loads the right facelet view by basing on the logged in user. The root path from where load the views are build dynamically by calling a service, and it's stored in the session.
Moreover the views can be placed in a folder outside the war package.
Im my facelet view I used the a placeholder 'skin-views' to identify the portion that will be substituted.

For example:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"     
template="/facelets/template.xml">

    ...
    <ui:define name="content">
       <ui:include src="skin-views/content.xhtml">
    </ui:define>
    ...

</ui:composition>
```

In the snippet above the page template is containted in the war package, 
whereas the placeholder 'skin-view' is substitued by the custom ResourceResolver that build the right lookup path.

for example:

```
skin-views => /home/user/skins/customSkin/
skin-views/content.xhtml => /home/user/skins/customSkin/content.xhtml
```

In the web.xml, I have set the following parameters:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.VIEW_MAPPINGS</param-name>
    <param-value>*.xhtml</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Added just for removing an annoying error message on startup -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>facelets.RECREATE_VALUE_EXPRESSION_ON_BUILD_BEFORE_RESTORE</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In conclusion the first time I logged in the views are loaded correctly, but If I log out and I log in with a different user with a different skin, the included fragment is the same of the previuos user. 
I suppose my understanding of facelets caching mechanins is wrong.
I've trid with facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD equal to 0 but nothing change.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Can't you dynamically resolve the desired path based on the contents of the user's session? I mean after a user has logged in and a `@SessionScoped` object has been instantiated for the user, you should be able to use some logic within that bean to generate the desired path, i.e. `<ui:include src="#{userSession.findRequiredFragment}">`

Comment: @kolossus you are right, but if possible I wouldn't pollute the pages with el expression.